# Duplicate hair curve Raidus control

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

What is connected to the Radius socket in this video?

https://video.blender.org/w/es5bkTNvRwrvUFdjuK1UvB?start=1s

[image]

Comment: There isn't a way for anyone to guess where that noodle connects to without seeing the source. Perhaps you can ask in the comments under the video, maybe the people who made the video will tell you. The video is unlisted, so I guess you found it from another source, which maybe shows the rest of the nodes?

Comment: The model looks like one of the original icons of the hair assets that come with Blender 3.5.